# Set subclass belongsTo relation to a specific value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Here's my schema:

```
Schema::create('agents', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->increments('name');
    $table->integer('agent_type_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('agent_type_id')->references('id')->on('agent_types');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('agent_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->increments('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And here is my `Agent` model:

```
class Agent extends Model
{

    public function agentType()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('AgentType');

    }

}
```

One particular `AgentType` record will have the title `Artist`. So I'd like to create an `Artist` model that extends `Agent`, and has its `agentType()` preset to point to that particular record. I'm going to have a a few different types of Agents, so I'm considering implementing this as a pattern for other agent types as well.

So a few questions:

- Is this good practice? Or should I run far, far away from this idea?
- How would I set the `agentType()` method in a child `Artist` class to point to a specific record to all instances of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Eloquent's [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) method to define a specific value for the descendant class:

```
class Artist extends Agent
{

    public function getAgentTypeAttribute()
    {

        AgentType::where('title', 'Artist')->first();

    }

}
```

Super-simple solution!

Comment: Consider leveraging model events for this, particularly `creating`. You can set the title attribute in each subclass and then query for the type as it's being created. It will provide a generic solution and save you from having an accessor method on every model. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events